# How to change the return type from Array.prototype.reduce?

Tags: typescript

I have an array of objects of type CustomObject, the objects have a field called stringArray that always has an array of strings.

I want to do something like this

```
const testArray = arrayOfObjects.reduce( (a,b) => {
   return a.stringArray.concat(b.stringArray);
});
```

The typescript compile complains that the return type is `string[]` whereas the actual return type should be of type `CustomObject`. Is there a way to force typescript to realise I am not trying to return `CustomObject` and instead want my new const testArray to be of `string[]` type?

I have tried `const testArray: string[] = ...` but this does not work.

Comment: Could you include what `arrayOfObjects` is?

Comment: Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 
showing the problem.
You can use the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) to make such an example

Answer (score 1):

One of your mistakes is that you want the return of the `reduce` to be equals to `string[]`, but at the same time you are trying to use `a` as `a.stringArray`.

Look at the following [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwgY2AEQgMwJYDtvDYD2uUAvFAN4BQUdAzsAE54DmAgk0wIYgBcURi1ysA2gF0A3NQC+06qEhROPEDEzwkqcrEQp0WPAWK4J85CUZRuXXus376AlXY17tFUTQbM2L-lCiAOSYRERB4gA0spFUtIK+Iv4CwXA2QbFBACZErBlQQcjcwBHRMlLU1Ba4VsAQjMkJwmLiOjaq9u7A9AB0TBBZAK7IEAAUo9wCQmwSsXACDqgYOPiEJACU5AB8cXRQ-cCDTKTcPdVFwKNwPdNJtiDr0jKxEo+V1fREADYQPV+5ozqDXujyAA).

```
type ObjectDefinition = {
   stringArray: string[];
};

type ArrayOfObject = ObjectDefinition[];

const arrayOfObjects: ArrayOfObject = [{
  stringArray: ['foo'],
}, {
  stringArray: ['bar', 'dog', 'cat'],
}];

const testArray: string[] = arrayOfObjects.reduce((a: string[], b: ObjectDefinition) => {
   return a.concat(b.stringArray);
}, []);

console.log(testArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

you must pass an empty string array as 2nd parameter to reduce

```
const reduced = customObjectArr.reduce(
  (acc, value) => acc.concat(value.stringArr),
  new Array<string>()
);
```

Then typescript can infer that the `acc` parameter and the return-type of `reduce ()` is a string array.

[Full Stacklbitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-65901527?file=index.ts)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the form of `Array.prototype.reduce()` with the initial value provided and also providing the correct type into generic:

```js
interface CustomObject {
    stringArray: string[];
}

const arrayOfObjects: CustomObject[] = [
    {
        stringArray: ['1', '2']
    },
    {
        stringArray: ['3', '4']
    }
];

const testArray = arrayOfObjects.reduce<string[]>( (acc, item) => {
   return acc.concat(item.stringArray);
}, []);
```